# Input form from javascript console Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I try to use Chrome console to input form Username and Password on this website: https://ucp.nordvpn.com/login/
but when click button Log in. It shows error "Username cannot be blank"

Please help me. Thank you

```
// Input prompt format user:password
var account = prompt('Account?');
if (account) {
    account = account.split(":");
    console.log(account);
    document.querySelector("#ucp_login_email_field").value = account[0];
    document.querySelector("#ucp_login_password_field").value = account[1];
    document.querySelector(".Button").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. please try this. But at first check **account** is empty or not.

```
// Input prompt format user:password
    var account = ["demo@gmail.com", "123456"]; 
    if (account) {
        console.log(account);
        document.querySelector("#ucp_login_email_field").value = account[0];
        document.querySelector("#ucp_login_password_field").value = account[1];
    };
    if (document.querySelector("#ucp_login_email_field").value != "" && document.querySelector("#ucp_login_password_field").value != ""){
        document.querySelector("form").submit();
    } else{
        console.log("fields are not filled correctly");
    }
```

Comment: I changed some code in my solution, please check this.

Comment: try $("form").submit(); and the above code will work fine.

Comment: Ok I can change it for you..... Thanks. So you should accept my answer.

Comment: Please try directly in that website. It does not work

Comment: Its working form me, I don't know why it is not working for yours!

Comment: You are in the write track, when you hit the login url with valid user and pass the backend will give you authorization token. The token is not processed correctly. Use valid user and pass, you can see good result. Signup needs credit card in that site. If you have the right credential it must work. thanks.

Comment: I use my account to login. Not invalid account

Answer (score -1):

When you type the values in the text box, values(username, password) are stored in variables. While submitting the form, values are taken from variable and overwrite your values(you assigned via chrome console) in the textbox.

So, your values can not be submitted through chrome console unless it is typed in the textbox.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: Textbox values are stored in variable during key press in textbox.  While click on Login button, values are taken from those variables not from the textbox.  In your case, you have not typed anything in the textbox. So, values would be empty in the variable. That is why, It shows error "Username cannot be blank".  Since it is not considering textbox values not entered without typing. you cannot assign it via chrome console.